# What is ZooKeeper and how zookeeper works?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am reading Apache ZooKeeper now. I looked many docs and articles in the Internet, but I got more and more confused about how ZooKeeper is exactly working?

For now, I know ZooKeeper provides an infrastructure for cross-node synchronization and can be   used by apps to ensure that tasks across the cluster are serialized or synchronized. It maintains a kind of tree file system which is composed by "znodes". So for example, I have a cluster which is one master and two followers, and in all servers this tree file system structure are always the same? If I create a new znode in one of follower server, the whole cluster will be synchronized this changing?

Another question is that each znode only can contains 1M data because ZooKeeper is not designed as a large data store to hold very large data values. But if I need a kind of distributed database which will store large data, how can I use ZooKeeper to achieve it? If this large data is not stored in znode, where should it store and how the ZooKeeper get this data?

Answer (score 1):

"But if I need a kind of distributed database which will store large data, how can I use ZooKeeper to achieve it?"  Don't.  A blender is not a car; Zookeeper is not a large data store.

Zookeeper is basically a [lock server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_lock_manager), and not meant to store large data.  Instead, it helps other large data stores (such as HBase) achieve [consistency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model) by exposing synchronization tools.

As an end user (someone who just wants to use a distributed database) zookeeper isn't very interesting.  It's target audience is service/data store authors who write the things that the end user probably wants.

Answer (score 1):

A ZooKeeper ensemble must be consistent as a majority (which includes the master): you have no guarantee that a particular node of the ensemble is up-to-date with the master. To have that guarantee you must actually write something through that node: then the node will be updated, following which it will post its update. This is because writes are linear, i.e., the writes are strictly ordered for consistency.

I would not use ZooKeeper for large storage, for the reason above: every time you store something, you force a majority of nodes to update. Frequent propagation of writes clearly goes against the distributed character you desire. Stick to ZooKeeper for *coordination* between clients, and leverage such coordination to perform your writes to an actual distributed/sharded database.

Comment: Could you help me to understand this topic?please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959775/how-to-push-jenkins-plugins-changes-using-zookeeper